# how can i find from all data i have add one lowest price in CLIPS

Tags: clips

I need to find the lowest price from all the data I enter. For example, I have tested the rule contain (defrule lowest and it works but when here it works in a loop). How can I resolve this situation?

**Start the program**

```
;; enter how many point you need to add ;;

(defrule lancesaisiepoint
?f1 <-  (debut point)
=>
    (retract ?f1)
    (printout t "Combien de point ");; type number;;
    (bind ?x (read))
    (assert (point ?x))
 )


(defrule saisiepoint
?f <-   (point ?a)
    (test (> ?a 0))
=>
 (printout t "Entrer nbr point " crlf)
(printout t "nom point ")
(bind ?x1 (read))
(printout t "Valeur point ")
(bind ?y1 (read))
(assert (point ?x1 ?y1))
(retract ?f)
(assert (point (- ?a 1)))
)


;;enter how manu moins(a variable) you need to add;; 

(defrule lancesaisiemoins
?f1 <-  (point 0)
=>
(retract ?f1)
(printout t "Combien de moins ");; type number ;;
(bind ?x (read))
(assert (moins ?x))
 )


(defrule saisiemoins
?f <-   (moins ?a)
(test (> ?a 0))
=>
(printout t "Entrer nbr moins" crlf) 
(printout t "nom moins ")
(bind ?x2 (read))
(printout t "Valeur moins ")
(bind ?y2 (read))
(assert (moins ?x2 ?y2))
(retract ?f)
(assert (moins(- ?a 1))))


(defrule supprnbrpoint ;compter
?x<-    (point 0)
=>
    (retract ?x)
    )

(defrule supprnbrmoins
?x<-    (moins 0)
=>
    (retract ?x)
    )


;; add information like path and cost ;;
(defrule table

?M <-   (point ?x1 ?y1) 
?K <-   (moins ?x2 ?y2)

=>
(printout t "donner les infos du chemin " ?x1 ?x2 crlf)
(printout t "path : ")
(bind ?p (readline))
(printout t "distance ")
(bind ?d (readline))
(assert (infos ?x1 to ?x2 path ?p distance ?d ))
)


(defrule path
?P <-   (point ?x1 ?y1)
?K <-   (moins ?x2 ?y2)
?Z <-   (infos ?x1 to ?x2 path ?p distance ?d )
=>  
(printout t " path de  " ?x1 ?x2 " est: " ?p " avec une distance de " ?d    crlf)
)

(defrule lowest
  (infos ?x1 to ?x2 path ?p distance ?d )
   (not  (distance ?d2&:(< ?d2 ?d)))
   =>
   (printout t "le chemin de " ?x1 " vers " ?x2 ","  ?p " has the lowest price: " ?d crlf))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or how to reproduce the problem you're encountering.

Comment: as you see i have after each information data,the lowest price of the same data repeating? and i need just lowest price of all the dataI ihope that it is clear now ?
CLIPS-- Combien de point 2
nom point A  Valeur point : 23
nom point B
Valeur point 34
Combien de moins 1
nom moins C
Valeur moins 43
donner les infos du chemin AC
path:ABC distance 3
path de AC est:ABC avec une distance de 3
le chemin de A vers C,ABC has the lowest price:3
donner les infos du chemin BC
path:BDC distance 23
path de BC est: BDC avec une distance de 23
le chemin de B vers C,BDC has the lowest price:23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following modifications to your rules:

```
(defrule table
   ?M <- (point ?x1 ?y1) 
   ?K <- (moins ?x2 ?y2)
   =>
   (printout t "donner les infos du chemin " ?x1 ?x2 crlf)
   (printout t "path : ")
   (bind ?p (readline))
   (printout t "distance ")
   (bind ?d (read)) ;; Use read not readline
   (assert (infos ?x1 to ?x2 path ?p distance ?d)))

(defrule lowest
  (declare (salience -10))                               ;; Rule needs to execute last
  (infos ?x1 to ?x2 path ?p distance ?d)
  (not (infos ? to ? path ? distance ?d2&:(< ?d2 ?d)))   ;; Need to match infos facts
  =>
  (printout t "le chemin de " ?x1 " vers " ?x2 ","  ?p " has the lowest price: " ?d crlf))
```

You'll get this behavior:

```
CLIPS> (assert (debut point))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
Combien de point 2
Entrer nbr point 
nom point A
Valeur point 23
Entrer nbr point 
nom point B
Valeur point 34
Combien de moins 1
Entrer nbr moins
nom moins C
Valeur moins 43
donner les infos du chemin AC
path : ABC
distance 3
 path de  AC est: ABC avec une distance de 3
donner les infos du chemin BC
path : BDC
distance 23
 path de  BC est: BDC avec une distance de 23
le chemin de A vers C,ABC has the lowest price: 3
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,now it s a very good programe ,thank you Mr Gary Riley for your answer

Comment: Dear Mr.Gary , because i am new in developpement of ES,plz i dont understand why a rule not work? for example i just modefy my program and add some fact in deffacts, I find  automatically the data that  i want but not the information of the lowest price ,thank you very much

Comment: If you have a separate issue, you should post a new question.